# Do we have kNNdistplot in Python

Tags: python, knn

There is a function called kNNdistplot to draw the k-distance plot.
Do we have a (similar) kNNdistplot function in Python?

Comment: Look at the knn tag, you'll see users there with python and R examples from what I can tell.

Comment: Looking for [this](https://github.com/vincewide/ML_scheduler/blob/a9225d15dcbbbbfc3ffefa58560369cbf0f9f704/DBSCAN.py#L55)?

Comment: Thanks, mat be I should ask more basic question that how do we calculate the k-distance in python